# function that prints multidimensional list elements nested by their dimension:

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function that accepts multidimensional list and prints out list elements nested by their dimensions

Example input :[[1, 2, [3, 4, [6]]], [[], [], [3, 4, 5]]]

Output :

```
    # 1, 2
    #      3, 4
    #          6
    #
    #
    #       3, 4, 5
    #
```

So far i tried this:

```
def print_list(lst, spaces=1):
    for i in lst:
        if isinstance(i, list):
            print_list(i, spaces + 1)
            #print("\n")
        else:
             s = (", ".join(str(i)for i in lst))
             print("  " * spaces + str(s))

mylst = [[1, 2, [3, 4, [6]]], [[], [], [3, 4, 5,]]]
print_list(mylst)
```

but cant get the desired output. Can you help me and explain how i can achieve this?

Comment: While iterating; every time you *go deeper* into a list increase the spacing; when the list you are *in* finishes decrease the spacing. `indent = '   '` - `indent*0`, `indent*1`,... or use tab characters '\t', '\t\t'.

Comment: What if array is followed by non-array item?

Comment: the spacing looks right by now i just cant figure out how to print the 1,2 on one line and others on the next lines like 3,4,5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution also deals with non-list items that follow after an instance of list. Each dimension is named a `level`. The levels without non-list items are ignored.

```py
import dataclasses as dc

@dc.dataclass
class Level:
    level: int
    items: list

def get_levels(_list: list, level: int = 0):
    items = [item for item in _list if not isinstance(item, list)]
    levels = []

    # Ignore level without non-list items
    if items:
        levels.append(Level(level, items))

    for lower_list in (get_levels(item, level + 1) for item in _list if isinstance(item, list)):
        levels.extend(lower_list)
    return levels

def print_list(_list: list):
    levels = get_levels(_list)
    # Start from the first level with non-list items
    min_level = min(level.level for level in levels)

    for level in levels:
        print("  " * (level.level - min_level), ", ".join(map(str, level.items)), sep="")

# The original input
print("mylst:")
mylst = [[1, 2, [3, 4, [6]]], [[], [], [3, 4, 5,]]]
print_list(mylst)

# Input with non-list items after a list
print("\nmylst_1:")
mylst_1 = [[1, 2, [3, 4, [6], 7, 8]], [[], [], [3, 4, 5,], 6, 7]]
print_list(mylst_1)
```

Output:

```
mylst:
1, 2
  3, 4
    6
  3, 4, 5

mylst_1:
1, 2
  3, 4, 7, 8
    6
6, 7
  3, 4, 5
```

The solution uses data classes so you need Python version 3.7 or higher. However, data classes can be easily replaced with a plain class if you use a lower version.

Answer (score 0):

`print` allows to provide `end` parameter which can be used to prevent going to a new line after print:

```py
def print_list(lst, spaces=1):
    for i in lst:
        print(' '*spaces, end="") # print current indentation
        if isinstance(i, list):
            print() # print new line for array
            print_list(i, spaces + 1) 
        else:
            print(i, end=" ") # print current element
```